# How to sort dataframe by specific data in a column

Tags: pandas, sorting

So, I am studying pandas and one of the tasks was to sort values of the table by borough and holidays(data in this column is only "Y"(if it is holiday) and "N"(if not). Also I avereged pickups(as task asked), but I wanna show data specifically on "Y".

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("2_taxi_nyc.csv")
df.groupby(["borough", "hday"]).agg({"pickups": 'mean'})type here
```

Result:

[image]

I tried using df.query, but it didn`t work (error was smth like exp is not supposed to be a "class bool" and in another try a "list"). After that I`ve been stuck and still can`t find a solution or even an idea how to solve this in the Net. I hope someone will help me. I apologize for my poor english(not a first language). Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1- provide a [mre], an image is not reproducible, 2- provide the exact expected output, 3- show what you tried exactly ("*tried using df.query*" is too vague).

Comment: Please edit your post so as to share data as [**text, not images**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
To share dataframes: output of `print(df)` or `print(df.to_dict())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do that:

1. filter results after aggregation
2. filter data before aggregation

Case 1:

```
>>> (df.groupby(['borough', 'hday'], as_index=False)  # <- group labels as columns
       .agg({'pickups': 'mean'}).query("hday == 'Y'"))  # <- filter with query

          borough hday      pickups
1           Bronx    Y    48.065868
3        Brooklyn    Y   527.011976
5             EWR    Y     0.041916
7       Manhattan    Y  2035.928144
9          Queens    Y   320.730539
11  Staten Island    Y     1.497006
```

Case 2:

```
>>> df[df['hday'] == 'Y'].groupby('borough', as_index=False)['pickups'].mean()
         borough      pickups
0          Bronx    48.065868
1       Brooklyn   527.011976
2            EWR     0.041916
3      Manhattan  2035.928144
4         Queens   320.730539
5  Staten Island     1.497006
```

Source dataset: [uber_nyc_enriched.csv](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/yannisp/uber-pickups-enriched)